# In how many ways can n hyperplanes in R(n) intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

There are eight ways that 3 planes can intersect in R(3): 1) Intersect at a point; 2) Each plane cuts the other two in a line; 3) 2 parallel planes, 3rd plane cuts each in a line; 4) 2 coincident planes, 3rd plane parallel; 5) 3 parallel planes; 6) 3 planes intersect in line; 7) 2 planes coincide and 3rd plane intersects them in a line; 8) 3 coincident planes.

Organizing this way, how many ways can 4 hyperplanes intersect in R(4)? In general, how many ways can n hyperplanes intersect in R(n)?

Comment: I should have said how many ways can the hyperplanes intersect or not intersect?

Comment: In how many ways can you partition $n$ objects into non-empty subsets?

Comment: But if I partition 3 objects into non-empty subsets, the maximum number of ways is 7 (unless I've made an error). Yet the number of ways 3 planes can intersect (or not) is 8, as I described in my question. Please let me know if I'm not thinking about this correctly.